# Decimal Number Formatting in Input

Tags: javascript, forms, string-formatting, number-formatting

Currently I am facing an issue in formatting decimals.

On the blur event of the text box, if the user enters:

```
1) 1    -> this should be converted to 001.00
2) 2.5  -> this should be converted to 002.50
3) .5   -> this should be converted to 000.50
4) 12.4 -> this should be converted to 012.40
```

All inputs should be converted to the same format upon leaving the input or losing focus.

Comment: Need more info.  You want this converted in the input field?  In the post?  On the server before validating?  Are you using jQuery or any other JS framework?  Cheers

Comment: Yes it should be converted while leaving the textbox in client side using pure Javascript.Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" onblur="formatDecimal(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatDecimal(input) {
        var val = '' + (+input.value);
        if (val) {
            val = val.split('\.');
            var out = val[0];
            while (out.length < 3) {
                out = '0' + out;
            }
            if (val[1]) {
                out = out + '.' + val[1]
                if (out.length < 6) out = out + '0';
            } else {
                out = out + '.00';
            }
            input.value = out;
        } else {
            input.value = '000.00';
        }
    }
</script>
```